# Problem addin package npm to asp net visual studio 2017

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

i have an issue here : when installing my package via command line in my asp net 4.5 web app,
these line are not recognized

```
<script src="@serverUrl/node_modules/@devexpress/analytics-core/dist/js/dx-analytics-core.min.js"></script>
```

But yet the package exist and is here in my explorer ...

Comment: Try,                                                                                                                        
1.Delete all the folders inside of the packages folder.
2.Update all packages in Nuget Package Manager. @Razgort

Comment: but the package is not in nugget but in npm ...

Comment: okey, npm cache clean and npm update try please

Comment: i tried to downloaded them from source and added them like that :    <!-- 3rd-party dependencies -->
    <script src="" @serverUrl/Content/Scripts/devexpress/globalize/number.js"></script>
    <script src="" @serverUrl/Content/Scripts/devexpress/globalize/currency.js"></script>
    <script src="" @serverUrl/Content/Scripts/devexpress/globalize/date.js"></script>

Comment: But now there s an other issue see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54251506/using-a-js-lib-in-typescript-without-definitely-typed-definition

Comment: Okey, sorry i can't help @Razgort