# Using a JS lib in typescript without definitely typed definition

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I have an AspNet app using typescript with onsen ui.
When i called component from onsen, i used these ref

```
 // <reference path="TypeScriptHelper/Onsen/OnsPageController.ts"/>
```

But i want to use a javascript lib called devexpress that has no .d.ts defintion
How can i called these controls from my typescript file ?

The script are inserted in the index.html
But when i call them in my typescript file like this :

```
    DevExpress.Dashboard.ResourceManager.embedBundledResources();
    // Creates a new Web Dashboard control with the specified ID and settings:
    var dashboardControl = new DevExpress.Dashboard.DashboardControl(document.getElementById("container"), {
        // Configures an URL where the Web Dashboard's server-side is hosted:
        endpoint: "https://demos.devexpress.com/services/dashboard/api",
        workingMode: "Viewer",
        extensions: {
            "dashboard-panel": (control) => new DevExpress.Dashboard.DashboardPanelExtension(control)
        }
    });
```

They are not recognized
Any idea why and how to fixe it ?

Thx in advance,

Comment: ANy idea guys ?

Comment: How can i add the missing controls ? i've never done any typescript .d.ts –